# Showing equivalence between two constrained maximisation problems

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, maxima-minima, constraints

I have a constrained maximisation problem (problem **1** below) and I would like your help to understand whether it is equivalent to problem **2**. My intuition is that they are equivalent but I don't know how to prove it and hence I'm not sure.

**Notation:**

- $\mathcal{I}\equiv \{1,2,...,I\}$, $\mathcal{J}\equiv \{1,2,...,J\}$
- Unknowns: $x_{ij}$ $\forall (i,j)\in \mathcal{I}\times \mathcal{J}$, $x_{i0}$ $\forall i\in \mathcal{I}$, and $x_{0j}$ $\forall j \in \mathcal{J}$
- $x$ denotes the vector of all unknowns of dimension $IJ+I+J$
- $\tilde{x}\equiv (x_{ij}$ $\forall (i,j)\in \mathcal{I}\times \mathcal{J})$
- Known parameters: $A_{ij}$ $\forall (i,j)\in \mathcal{I}\times \mathcal{J}$, $A_{i0}$ $\forall i\in \mathcal{I}$, and $A_{0j}$ $\forall j \in \mathcal{J}$

**Problem 1:**

$$
\max_x\Big[ \sum_{i=1}^I x_{i0}A_{i0}+\sum_{j=1}^J x_{0j}A_{0j}+\sum_{i=1}^I \sum_{j=1}^J x_{ij} A_{ij}\Big]
$$
$$
\text{ s.t. } \sum_{j=0}^J x_{ij}=1 \text{ }\forall i \in \mathcal{I}\text{, }\sum_{i=0}^I x_{ij}=1 \text{ }\forall j \in \mathcal{J}\text{, } x\in \{0,1\}^{IJ+I+J}
$$

**Problem 2:**

$$
\max_\tilde{x}\Big[ \sum_{i=1}^I \sum_{j=1}^J x_{ij} (A_{ij}-A_{i0}-A_{0j})\Big]
$$
$$
\text{ s.t. } \sum_{j=1}^J x_{ij}\leq 1 \text{ }\forall i \in \mathcal{I}\text{, }\sum_{i=1}^I x_{ij}\leq 1 \text{ }\forall j \in \mathcal{J}\text{, } \tilde{x}\in \{0,1\}^{IJ}
$$

Any hint?

Comment: Take $x_{i0} = 1-\sum_{j=1}^J x_{ij}$ and note you can remove a constant from the objective function without altering the problem.

Comment: @LinAlg Is this correct: $$
\max_x\Big[ \sum_{i=1}^I x_{i0}A_{i0}+\sum_{j=1}^J x_{0j}A_{0j}+\sum_{i=1}^I \sum_{j=1}^J x_{ij} A_{ij}\Big]
$$ equivalent to $$
\max_{\tilde{x}}\Big[ \sum_{i=1}^I A_{i0}-\sum_{i=1}^ I\sum_{j=1}^Jx_{ij}A_{i0}+\sum_{j=1}^J A_{0j}-\sum_{i=1}^ I\sum_{j=1}^Jx_{ij}A_{0j}+\sum_{i=1}^I \sum_{j=1}^J x_{ij} A_{ij}\Big]
$$ equivalent to $$
\max_{\tilde{x}}\Big[ -\sum_{i=1}^ I\sum_{j=1}^Jx_{ij}A_{i0}-\sum_{i=1}^ I\sum_{j=1}^Jx_{ij}A_{0j}+\sum_{i=1}^I \sum_{j=1}^J x_{ij} A_{ij}\Big]
$$

Comment: equivalent to $$
\max_{\tilde{x}}\Big[ \sum_{i=1}^I \sum_{j=1}^J x_{ij} (A_{ij}-A_{i0}-A_{0j}\Big]
$$

Comment: Is this enough to show what I want?

Comment: Why the doubt? The "$=1$" and "$\leq 1$" constraints are obviously also equivalent.